# Spring boot validate that field is of type string

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class that represents form submit:

```
Class Form {
   // @String(message = "Invalid type")
   private String name;
}
```

I was looking for a `javax.validation` annotation to put on top of the `name` field, that will validate that the field is indeed of type string, and if not, display an appropriate error message, but I couldn't find one. What's the way to do it?

**Clarification:**

What bothers me is a case where someone sends one of the following payloads, and I still haven't seen a solution for that:

```
{
  name: true
}
```

or

```
{
  name: 1234
}
```

Comment: You already have the type as String. Are you want to check the characters have alphabets? Also `Class` is not Java.

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense. A bean validator validates a bean. The bean must exist in order to be validated. If the bean exists, then its name field can't possibly contain anything other than a String: Java is a type-safe language, and won't let you store a Date or an Integer in a variable of type String. So checking that a  variable of type String contains a String will obviously always return the same result: yes, it's a String.

Comment: But what if someone submits an integer?

Comment: @Mister_L An integer (represented by a sequence of characters) is also a string.

Comment: It depends on what creates and populates this bean. But most probably, name will contain the integer value, as a String.

Comment: That very much depends on context. What if you ... just try it? And you see, it also depends on your transport format. Say, some frontend creates JSON. And just uses "value" all over the place. Then everything that comes in **will** be a string. Sure, if one says "5", that would be a strange name. But it is still a string.

Comment: A `String` is text - any text. Us humans, we communicate with text. The only thing that cannot be represented as a `String` is unencoded binary. Therefore anything a _human_ is likely to enter into a form is going to be a `String`. Let's not even get into the fact that if it's a web form then all the fields are strings, so they cannot possibly enter anything else...

Answer (score 8):

If you want to validate the input to only have alphabets then use `@javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` like follows.

```java
class Form {
   @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z]*$",message = "Invalid Input")
   private String name;
}
```

This will validate that name will only have alphabet.